# Which will show up: an index.html file in a folder or a root html file?

Tags: html, hosting, directory-structure

If I have an index.html file in a folder named ‘about’ vs an about.html file in the main directory, which would show up when I type in www.example.com/about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html file in a folder named ‘about’ will show up by default when you access www.example.com/about